# Table element is not displayed in Jaspersoft Studio

Tags: csv, jasper-reports

I am trying to display a simple Table on my report; instead I see a blank page.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Created a new Data Adapter using CSV file.
2. Created a new report using that Data Adapter.
3. Added a Table element to Detail Band.
4. Click "Preview" and I can see only 2 blank pages.
5. If I change to use the built-in "Jasper Sample DB", I can see a Table with no problems.

I use Jaspersoft Studio 6.3.0 running on Windows 10. This is so simple and I cannot see why it does not work. I also search for solutions in many web sites but I cannot see any solutions. (Note: I can create Chart using that CSV Data Adapter with no problem.)

- If I use a database as datasource, I can see the sql SELECT in queryString tag. If I use CSV as datasource, I am expecting not to see a SELECT. This is correct in the source code XML file.

Thank you.

Comment: Try to move Table to Title band

Comment: Post the JRXML.

Comment: Hi @Dave, I cannot paste the JRXML code here as it has 197 lines. Stackoverflow said it is too big. Can I send you the file via email instead? I suspect that this may be a bug in Jasper Reports. All I did was to read a CSV file and put the content of it to a Table element. Very simple and it does not work.

Comment: Hi @Alex, I do not wish to put the Table in Title band. The reason is because I am producing a report for students. Each student will have a two page report and the table will be displayed on second page. Therefore Title Band is not the right place to put the Table in.

Comment: Hi Ben, You can use table in Summary band or in Title band and remove all other bands if not required. The table will display in second page too if you move the Table component to Summary band or Title band.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? i'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by doing this:

- No query in report, but in dataset, check if the query has results at data preview
- Moving the table to Summary section
- At report properties and table properties change "When data no Type" attribute to "All Sections No Detail"
- Also, idk if this helps, but right click on Dataset and select Connect to Main Dataset.

I hope it helps.